# How do I prove that $h \circ f$ is total?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that if functions $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $h : B \rightarrow C$ are total, then
$h \circ f$ is total.

Comment: "Total" does not normally mean "surjective". It means everywhere defined, i.e. an actual function rather than a partial function.

Comment: @Chris: I see. Well, it might not be a duplicate per se then. However if you look at the answer (or the argument) you can easily see it is really just the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $a\in A$. Since $f$ is total, then $f(a)$ is defined, and an element of $B$, and since $h$ is total, then $h(f(a))$ is defined.

Comment: Ah thanks! That makes sense. h is total, so, because the entire codomain of f is within B, $h(f(a))$ must be defined.